How to filter observations in a dataset smaller than x?
I have a dataset with individual-related data. To ensure that the participants cannot be identified because of certain characteristics, I have to combine observations with less than 20 observations per characteristic.
Using the iris dataset for reproducible purpose, I can find the number of observations for one variable (e.g. Sepal.Width) using summarytools::freq:
iris
summarytools::freq(iris$Sepal.Width)

However, is there a way to find all observations with less than 2 of all variables in this data, without addressing every variable individually?
Similar to summarytools::freq(iris$Sepal.Width), I want not just the summary for one variable, but for all variables in my dataset, when one group within a variable has a frequency less than a certain number. So something like summarytools::freq(iris) but conditioned on a certain number of observations per group in each variable.
Is there a way in dplyr to get such results?

Please provide desired output.

Similar to summarytools::freq(iris$Sepal.Width), I want not just the summary for one variable, but for alle variables in my dataset, when one group within a variable has a frequency less than a certain number. So something like summarytools::freq(iris) but conditioned on a certain number of observations per group in each variable. Is there a way in dplyr to get such results?

Could you edit your question to include the desired output?

Using this from a comment as a guideline:

I want to find all groups in my variables, where the frequency of observations is less than a certain number.

Assuming it makes sense to turn your variables into factors, you might consider lumping functions from forcats to find records where a variable value occurs less than n times:
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

iris_mask <- 
  iris |> 
  mutate(across(-Species, \(x) as.factor(x) |> fct_lump_min(2))) |> 
  mutate(any_lt_2 = rowSums(pick(-Species) == "Other") > 0)

# hand-picked range:
iris_mask[10:20,]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species any_lt_2
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa    FALSE
#> 11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa    FALSE
#> 12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa    FALSE
#> 13          4.8           3          1.4         0.1  setosa    FALSE
#> 14        Other           3        Other         0.1  setosa     TRUE
#> 15          5.8       Other          1.2         0.2  setosa     TRUE
#> 16          5.7       Other          1.5         0.4  setosa     TRUE
#> 17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa    FALSE
#> 18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa    FALSE
#> 19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa    FALSE
#> 20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa    FALSE

# use iris_mask$any_lt_2 to subset records (i.e. get rows 14, 15, 16, ...) :
iris[iris_mask$any_lt_2,]
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> 15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
#> 24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
#> 33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> 34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
#> 49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
#> 65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
#> 82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
#> 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica

Created on 2024-08-13 with reprex v2.1.1

Check the counts for each column, when grouped by value. Then use rowSums if all columns match the criteria, then subset:
# set the minimum freq
x = 5

library(data.table)
d <- iris
setDT(d)

# loop through columns get counts
for(i in names(d)[1:4]) d[, paste0("tmp_", i) := .N <= x, by = i ]

ix_keep <- rowSums(d[, 6:9] == 0)
res <- d[ ix_keep, 1:5 ]

#before
sapply(iris[, 1:4], function(i) min(table(i)))
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#            1            1            1            1 
#after
sapply(res[, 1:4], function(i) min(table(i)))
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#           11           11           22          149 


You can use table and which inside lapply and then Reduce with union to find the observations (row indices) that meet any of your conditions.
freq <- 2

freq.list <- lapply(iris[,1:4], \(x) {
  n <- table(x) < freq
  which(x %in% names(n)[n])}
  )

iris[Reduce(union, freq.list),]


    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa


Sorry, there seems to be a misunderstanding. When you use summarytools::freq(iris$Sepal.Width)you can see, that the Sepal.Width in group "2", "2.2", "2.3.", "2.4" have less than 5 observations. I want to find all groups in my variables, where the frequency of observations is less than a certain number.

Then just change ‘intersect’ to ‘union’
